# I am attempting to draw a wall of bricks in a round about way. For the Breakout game

Tags: java

I am not sure how to use the graphics draw method threw a whole bunch of extending classes and implementing classes and some are abstract and others are interfaces. At least it doesn't throw any compiler errors. But I am stuck at a Stack Overflow Run time exception.

First, I have to start out with this interface.

```
public interface Drawable{

    public abstract void draw(Graphics g);

}
```

Then it gets implemented by this abstract class. Although it doesn't implement any draw code.

```
public abstract class GameObject implements Drawable {}
```

It gets extended by the next Class. This is where i get a Stack Overflow Error at      draw(g);. 
Also at that line the net beans IDE gives me a hint that says: "The method draw may recurse if not overridden in subclasses."

```
public class Brick extends GameObject {
    private int height;
    private int width;
    Brick(int xPosition, int yPosition, int width, int height, Color color) {
        super(xPosition, yPosition, color);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    } 
     public void draw(Graphics g) {
        draw(g); // This line throws the Error.
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(xPosition, yPosition, width, height);
    }
}
```

The next bit is probably all wrong. I wrote a method to automate the Wall building. Then I call that method in the paint method. I should be able to muddle threw it, eventually, maybe, probably not. I don't think it has any thing to do with the error, but I included it just in case.

```
public class Game extends JPanel { 
int nBricks = 100;
Graphics g;    
public void Wall(int nBricks) {
        int yPosition = 0;
        for (int xPosition = 0; xPosition < nBricks * 10; xPosition += 10) {
            if (xPosition % 100 == 0) {
                yPosition += 5;
            }
            Brick brick = new Brick(xPosition, yPosition, 10, 5, Color.GRAY);
            brick.draw(g);
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        this.Wall(nBricks);

    }
}
```

And finally the main method is in this class.

```
public class GameFrame extends JFrame{
    private Game game;

    public GameFrame(){  
        game.setDoubleBuffered(true);            
        this.getContentPane().add(game); 
        this.pack();
        game.start();  
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run()  {
                new GameFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I should probably note that there are a bunch of other methods and classes that I left out. Reason being, is that they don't have any thing to do with drawing the bricks.

Comment: `draw(g)` is calling itself, hence the warning and StackOverflow error. I `think`  this was meant to be `super.draw` but seeing as the parent class does not implement the method you can probably remove that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have infinite recursion here

```
 public void draw(Graphics g) {
    draw(g); // This line throws the Error.
 }
```

The line `draw(g)` is calling itself. And when is called, it call again itself etc., so after some time it overflow.

Probably you wanted something like `g.draw();` instead? Or maybe `super.draw(g);`

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I just deleted the line that was throwing the error. For as simple i fix as it was, that took way to long for me to figure out.